# Find video files across drives and pass to VLC

Tags: automator, search, vlc

Over 8 or so external hard drives, I have ~40,000 video files, acquired over the course of 15 years of video production. On our screen in the lobby of our studio, we want all of these files to shuffle through VLC. I have tried Find Any File and while that works great to locate the files, it always crashes when trying to pass that many to VLC. It used to work a few Mac OSes ago, but then some security updates got in the way. Automator can find them but gets stuck trying to pass them as well. Finder search can't really find them all. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With that many files, you may have to move over small amounts at a time. Search for video files with filenames that contain the letter "Z", then search for "Q", etc.

Comment: For a cycling 'advert' player, I would seriously reconsider running this data constantly from the original drives. I'd move them all to a 'player' drive, even taking the opportunity to lighten them for casual playback, then hammer that drive until it dies, rinse, repeat. [Background - I used to supervise several thousand similar displays in retail - it's amazing how much thrashing that type of system gets in just a few years. For single or just one or two video playbacks, we would transfer them to RAM, to extend their lives still further] That would also alleviate your 'find'.

Comment: Thank you, both. Very good ideas and I will see how I can implement them in my setup.